# Revtex 4.1 using superscript and square bracket style of citation in the same article

Tags: revtex

I am preparing an manuscript for an AIP journal and using Revtex 4.1.  By default AIP uses superscript citation style.  However, sometimes I'd like to use square-bracket style in the text when explicitly refer to another article, e.g. "see Fig. 1 in Ref. [30]".  How do I switch to square-bracket style just for that place while use superscript style elsewhere??

Answer (score 3):

Use `[\onlinecite{label}]`. Additional cite commands are explained in the revtex manual.